# Google Espresso: Do I need application code in my workspace along with test project?

Tags: android-espresso

I am not Android developer and I am evaluating Google Espresso tool for my mobile testing. Do I need application that I want to test to import and run in Eclipse or can I only install APK and read IDs from source code (like when you do e.g. Selenium testing)? In another words,can I have my test project totally separate from developer's code or I need to carry their code in my workspace?

Answer (score 0):

I also looked for a similar solution but to the best of my knowledge, this is **not** an option that is currently available in Android Studio. The test project must be built along with the application under test and deployed to an emulator or device.